# Forcibly rollback an installer in c# setup projects

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have created a custom action dll.I just want to check if a product with same name exists(Done).If yes tell the user to uninstall the product by throwing a InstallException.However if the products are installed in same directory the Install state of the prev product is removed & the install state of new product is copied in the base directory,due to which the prev product cannot be uninstalled.Is there any procedure to achieve a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want to use the Upgrade logic provided by the Windows Installer to find the other products and set a Property.  The Property can then control a LaunchCondition (or a Type19 CustomAction).  That way you don't need any CustomActions.